# Automated Forest Change Detection

Tags: arcgis-10.0, remote-sensing, erdas-imagine, software-recommendations, change-detection

Using two different time of images in the same places. Can i develop an automated change detection for forest area?

What / which are the suitable software to used?

Comment: I developed a software to do change detection using Landsat 8 Imagery: https://github.com/ibamacsr/indicar-tools It was tested only in GNU/Linux yet.

Answer (score 1):

Erdas Imagine has an add-on called [DeltaCue](http://www.geosystems.pl/upload/zalaczniki/IMAGINE%20DeltaCue%20Brochure.pdf) that is designed for this type of analysis. Some of the highlights include:

1. Multiple change detection algorithms: Magnitude, TC, Primary Color,
   Single Band, Band Slope.
2. Automatic percent change thresholding.
3. Change filtering based on spectral class, material type, area of
   change, and shape of change.
4. Automatic preprocessing: image cropping and radiometric correction.

There are a variety of videos on the subject too: [video 1 (French)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKZK_Pk4YXM), [video 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8zPgIAHgHik).

Answer (score 0):

In my company we are using Definiens Developer http://developer.definiens.com/ for checking changes in time, ie Open Lands, woodland losses (illegal fellings, windblows, etc), new plantings… This software is also being used in oncology so don’t be surprised. Please check it out maybe you will find it any useful.

Answer (score 0):

You cite ArcGIS and Erdas. Any of those software could help, but I would rather use Erdas than ArcGIS for remote sensing application (and if you want to use ArcGIS, you need the spatial analyst extension).

For other softwares, your should consider QGIS, with GRASS or OTB (free and open source) as well as ENVI or Definiens.

Comment: Yup.. Actually my dept already develop a system for our forest monitoring. Using arcgis spatial analysis, arcgis desktop, arcgis server, dreamveawer, java,phyton, etc. the problem now. We have to monitor the changes manually. Which is so difficult for large area or small thing changes. So there where the automated changes detection suggested

Comment: I think that you should then focus more on the algorithm than on the software. Therefore information about your input data is important.